# Помогите расшифровать параметры вывода fprintf

Tags: c, вывод, форматирование, fprintf

Есть код:

```
 fprintf(file, "%0*s", indent * times, " ");
```

Прочитав тонну сайтов, все равно из-за малого количества опыта - не пойму как расшифровывается `"%0*s"` и какой будет вывод.

Спасибо

Comment: Вообще-то 0 для `s` дает неопределенное поведение, а `*` — минимальную ширину поля. Так что у вас будет просто `indent * times` пробелов...

Comment: @Harry визуально - действительно так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то 0 для `s` *формально* дает неопределенное поведение:

> 0 : for integer and floating point number conversions, leading zeros are used to pad the field instead of space characters. For integer numbers it is ignored if the precision is explicitly specified. For other conversions using this flag results in undefined behavior. It is ignored if - flag is present.

а `*` — минимальную ширину поля:

> integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type int, which appears before the argument to be converted and the argument supplying precision if one is supplied. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the - flag specified and positive field width. (Note: This is the minimum width: The value is never truncated.)

Так что у вас будет просто `indent * times - 1` *чего-то* — например, в случае VC++ — таки ноликов, с последующим пробелом.

Цитированный текст взят отсюда: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Мне не дает отметить ваш ответ пока: Вы можете принять ответ через 6 минут. 
Как пройдет время - отмечу

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: отметил) Сорри, что немного задержался